# How to group subset data by irregular column values

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy, select

I have a dataframe:

```
        id      timestamp               value   start 
31833   32074   2012-01-06 15:20:09.830 45.0    0
31834   32075   2012-01-06 15:20:09.930 45.5    1
31835   32076   2012-01-06 15:20:18.833 25.0    0
...

50000   32076   2012-12-27 15:20:18.833 15.0    1
50000   32076   2012-12-28 22:12:18.833 15.0    0
50000   32076   2012-12-29 23:00:18.833 15.0    0
```

`start` is dummy variable taking `0` or `1` and are not at regular spaced intervals(comes at random intervals) in the dataframe. How can I group the data into sub datasets which start from `start ==1` until right before the next `start ==1`, so that I can calculate average of `value` in each sub dataset?

What are some methods I can use to achieve this? Must I use a while loop? I have not done anything like this before, just want some ideas. Thx

Expected output:

```
        id      timestamp_when_start=1   last_timestamp_in_subdataset  average 
31833   32074   2012-01-06 15:20:09.830  2012-01-06 15:20:09.830       40
31834   32075   2012-01-06 15:20:09.930  2012-01-06 15:20:09.930       35
31835   32076   2012-01-06 15:20:18.833  2012-01-06 15:20:18.833       35
31836   32077   2012-01-06 15:20:20.835  2012-01-06 15:20:20.835       35
...
```

or

```
        id      timestamp               value   start  average
31833   32074   2012-01-06 15:20:09.830 45.0    0      40
31834   32075   2012-01-06 15:20:09.930 45.5    1      35
31835   32076   2012-01-06 15:20:18.833 25.0    0      35
31836   32077   2012-01-06 15:20:20.835 38.0    0      35
...
```

Comment: could you post sample of dataset and expected output of that sample.except head and tail of the dataset.

Comment: Hi @RajithThennakoon you mean more sample?

Comment: `df.groupby(df['start'].cumsum())['value'].transform('mean')`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore reproducible  input dataframe

Comment: @Ben.T thank you! That works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben.T suggested, first create a group variable by doing a `cumsum` of the start

```
df['group'] = df['start'].cumsum()
```

Then groupby and do the aggregation

```
df.groupby('group').agg({'id':'min', 'timestamp':['min', 'max'], 'value':'mean'})
```